# Integral of $\vert x \vert^{-\alpha}$ over balls centered away from the origin

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Usually we like radially symmetric functions if we want to integrate over domains which are radially symmetric too (in polar coordinates this becomes a $1$d integral). Recently I tried to compute the following integral

\begin{equation}
I(x_0, r, \alpha, d):=\int_{B(x_0,r)} \frac{1}{\vert y \vert^\alpha} dy 
\end{equation}

where $\alpha \in (0,2)$, $B(x_0,r)\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a ball of radius $r$ centered at $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $d\geq 2$. For $x_0=0$ this is integral is easy to compute, however, for any $x_0\neq 0$ I would not know how to approach this.

For $d=2$ and $\vert x \vert >r$, we can rewrite the integral above as (I use $R=\vert x_0 \vert$)
$$ I(x_0,r, \alpha, 2)=\int_{-r}^r \frac{2}{(R +s)^{\alpha-1}} \arctan\left( 2R\frac{\sqrt{(R+s)^2-\left( \frac{(R+s)^2+R^2-r^2}{2R} \right)^2}}{(R+s)^2+R^2-r^2} \right) ds, $$

which Wolfram did not want to solve. The above was obtained by passing to spherical coordinates (the $\arctan$ expression corresponds to the length of the part of the sphere of radius $R+s$ centered at the origin which intersects $B(x_0,r)$). My question is

> Is there a closed form for $I(x_0,r,\alpha, d)$ for $x_0\neq 0$?

Comment: You should at least start with the change of variable $s = Rt$ to make the integral more readable.

Comment: @LL3.14 My goal here was more to make it possible for people to recognize how I set the integral up. While I could show some of my unsuccessful substitution in the end all of this is not really too helpful as I don't see how to even set up the corresponding integral in higher dimensions. I guess some more general principle would be needed if this really admits a closed form.